# react-query, react-router: issues with browsing to a page with non-cached content, then navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I run a small blog. I use react-query to cache the response from a fetch endpoint where the YAML files with the content are stored. This works fine and on navigating back from a blog article, the content is cached. However, if an article is read, reloaded, then you navigate back to the main page, an error is thrown.

`A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator. To fix, updates that suspend should be wrapped with startTransition.`

here is my entrypoint. i am using vite and react 18.20.

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import React from "react"
import Index from "./pages/Index.jsx"
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client"
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom"
import Error from "./pages/Error.jsx"
import Post from "./pages/Post.jsx"
import Minesweeper from "./pages/Minesweeper.jsx"
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query"

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Index />,
        errorElement: <Error />
    },
    {
        path: "/posts/:postid",
        element: <Post />,
        errorElement: <Error />
    },
    {
        path: "/minesweeper",
        element: <Minesweeper />,
    }
])

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
)
```

This is the component i use within `<Index />` with useQuery() to cache the content.

```js
import React, { startTransition } from "react"
import matter from "gray-matter"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"

const sort = (a, b) => {
    if (a.data.date < b.data.date) {
        return 1
    }
    return -1
}

async function getPosts() {
    try {
        let masterlist = await fetch("/posts/masterlist.json")
        const masterlistJSON = await masterlist.json()
        const posts = masterlistJSON.map((post) => `/posts/${post}`)
        const headers = new Headers()
        headers.set("Accept", "text/markdown")
        const postURLArrayMap = await Promise.all(
            posts.map((post) => (
                fetch(post, {headers})
                    .then((res) => res.text())
            ))
        )
        const parsedPosts = postURLArrayMap.map((post) => matter(post))
        parsedPosts.sort(sort)
        return parsedPosts
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return err
    }
}

export default function IndexPosts() {
    const { isPending, isError, data, error } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["posts"],
        queryFn: async () => {
            return await getPosts()
        },
    })

    if (isPending) {
        return <></>
    }

    if (isError) {
        return <h4>{error.message}</h4>
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h2 className="highlighted">articles</h2>
            <div id="articles">
                {
                    data.map((post, index) => (
                        <article key={index}>
                            <div className="card">
                                <img src="/graphics/anon.png" alt="tumblr anonymous grey face with sunglasses" height={80} width={80} />
                                <Link to={`/posts/${post.data.name}`}>{post.data.title}</Link>
                                <p>{new Date(post.data.date).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Here's the full stacktrace. It's typical react gibberish but at least i cant see the word hydration anywhere:

```
React Router caught the following error during render Error: A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator. To fix, updates that suspend should be wrapped with startTransition.
    throwException chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:21657
    handleError chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26470
    renderRootSync chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26555
    recoverFromConcurrentError chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26172
    performSyncWorkOnRoot chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26315
    flushSyncCallbacks chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:16575
    ensureRootIsScheduled chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26063
    ensureRootIsScheduled chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26061
    scheduleUpdateOnFiber chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:25998
    dispatchSetState chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:20466
    setState react-router-dom.js:4529
    optInStartTransition react-router-dom.js:4509
    setState react-router-dom.js:4529
    updateState react-router-dom.js:1276
    updateState react-router-dom.js:1276
    completeNavigation react-router-dom.js:1351
    handleLoaders react-router-dom.js:1616
    startNavigation react-router-dom.js:1524
    navigate react-router-dom.js:1427
    navigate react-router-dom.js:3850
    useLinkClickHandler react-router-dom.js:5013
    handleClick react-router-dom.js:4829
    callCallback2 chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11114
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11139
    invokeGuardedCallback chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11173
    invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11176
    executeDispatch chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14456
    processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14476
    processDispatchQueue chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14485
    dispatchEventsForPlugins chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14493
    dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14617
    batchedUpdates$1 chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26349
    batchedUpdates chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11019
    dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14616
    dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:12918
    dispatchEvent chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:12912
    dispatchDiscreteEvent chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:12889
 
Object { componentStack: "\nLazy\ndiv\nfooter\ndiv\nmain\nIndex\nRenderedRoute@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=d9949c6e:3560:7\nRenderErrorBoundary@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=d9949c6e:3517:5\nDataRoutes@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=d9949c6e:4663:7\nRouter@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=d9949c6e:3942:7\nRouterProvider@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=d9949c6e:4480:7\nQueryClientProvider@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/@tanstack_react-query.js?v=d9949c6e:2621:27" }
react-router-dom.js:3554:12
    componentDidCatch react-router-dom.js:3554
    callback chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:21528
    callCallback chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:17951
    commitUpdateQueue chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:17968
    commitLayoutEffectOnFiber chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:24505
    commitLayoutMountEffects_complete chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:25416
    commitLayoutEffects_begin chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:25405
    commitLayoutEffects chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:25356
    commitRootImpl chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26789
    commitRoot chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26713
    performSyncWorkOnRoot chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26331
    flushSyncCallbacks chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:16575
    ensureRootIsScheduled chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26063
    (Async: VoidFunction)
    ensureRootIsScheduled chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26061
    scheduleUpdateOnFiber chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:25998
    dispatchSetState chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:20466
    setState react-router-dom.js:4529
    optInStartTransition react-router-dom.js:4509
    setState react-router-dom.js:4529
    updateState react-router-dom.js:1276
    updateState react-router-dom.js:1276
    completeNavigation react-router-dom.js:1351
    handleLoaders react-router-dom.js:1616
    startNavigation react-router-dom.js:1524
    navigate react-router-dom.js:1427
    navigate react-router-dom.js:3850
    useLinkClickHandler react-router-dom.js:5013
    handleClick react-router-dom.js:4829
    callCallback2 chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11114
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11139
    invokeGuardedCallback chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11173
    invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11176
    executeDispatch chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14456
    processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14476
    processDispatchQueue chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14485
    dispatchEventsForPlugins chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14493
    dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14617
    batchedUpdates$1 chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:26349
    batchedUpdates chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:11019
    dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:14616
    dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:12918
    dispatchEvent chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:12912
    dispatchDiscreteEvent chunk-RZQHDLBT.js:12889
```

So far, I've attempted to wrap various things in startTransition, add the devtools to check what's erroring, but no cigar sadly.

I also attempted to use `<Suspense />` with a fallback but this was no different.

Comment: If you comment out the `useQuery` code, or mock it to just return an object to destructure from do you see the same issue?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, without useQuery the error persists with the same stack trace. Creating a mock value for data will render elements as expected but on reloading and then navigating back to the main page using the back arrow or link at the bottom brings up the error component set in the entrypoint. reloading this page makes it work as intended but it just seems like such a strange error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the lazy imports i was using for some static components. Importing these using standard ES6 syntax made it work perfectly.

Comment: Where were you using dynamic imports?

Comment: within a component called index which a lot of people tend to call <App />, the base route essentially. I thought it was inconsequential due to the stack traces pointing to the router.

Comment: I see, so in `Index` before `IndexPosts`. I would suggest editing your post to include that as part of your [mcve]. Glad it is working for you now.